# Можно ли javascript использовать в качестве генератора новой страницы?

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли в javascript сгенерировать код новой страницы, а потом выполнить его в новом окне? Я понимаю никто язык PHP не отменял но все же...

Пишу игровой скрипт, будет не размерное игровое поле, возможно очень большое в ширину и хотел бы чтобы это поле и игра открывалась в новом окне.

Comment: В текущем виде на ваш вопрос невозможно дать лаконичный ответ. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, какие технологии используете и что хотите видеть в ответе.

Comment: обновил ответ..

Comment: @perfect, даже с учетом того, что это можно сделать через JS, так делать не стоит

Comment: @DmitriySimushev у меня выхода другого нет так как поле не впишится в дизайн сайта

Comment: @perfect, выход есть всегда. Ну и решение все равно за вами, я лишь указал на запредельную костыльность вашего подхода =)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev я только что кодить на javascript начал (для развития) и подозреваю костылей еще очень много впереди )

Answer (score 1):

Да это вполне реально. JS может создать(открыть) новое окно и наполнить его содержимым. Например:

```
var newWin = window.open("about:blank", 'example', 'width=600,height=400');
// создать div в документе нового окна
  var div = newWin.document.createElement('div'),
    body = newWin.document.body;

  div.innerHTML = 'Добро пожаловать!'
  div.style.fontSize = '30px'

  // вставить первым элементом в body нового окна
  body.insertBefore(div, body.firstChild);
```

Пример взят частично [отсюда](https://learn.javascript.ru/window-methods)